# Converting left outer join on two queries to LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have below sql query which I want to convert into LINQ to obtain exactly same results and returned by below query

```
    select *
             from (
                select distinct DocID 
                from UserViewDoc 
                where UserViewDoc.UVID in (102558)) a 
         left outer join
            (
                select distinct UserViewDoc.DocID 
                from UserViewDoc 
                     inner join UserViewHeader on UserViewDoc.UVID =        UserViewHeader.UVID 
                where UserViewDoc.UVID not in (102558) 
                  and UserViewHeader.IsLock = 1) b on a.DocID = b.DocID
         where b.DocID is  null
         )
```

What I have tried so far is below LINQ statement

```
   var v = (from uvd in this.ViewSelectorControl.LDReviewContext.GetTable<UserViewDoc>()
                 where IDs.Contains(uvd.UVID)
                 select new { uvd.DocID, uvd.UVID });
        var c = ((from uvd in this.ViewSelectorControl.LDReviewContext.GetTable<UserViewDoc>()
                 join uvh in this.ViewSelectorControl.LDReviewContext.GetTable<UserViewHeader>() on uvd.UVID equals uvh.UVID
                 where !IDs.Contains(uvh.UVID) && uvh.IsLock == true
                 select new { uvd.DocID, uvd.UVID } ));
        var d = (from id in v
                 join ids in c on id.UVID equals ids.UVID into vc
                 from sub in vc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where sub == null
                 select id);
```

The problem I am facing is running the SQL query is returning 30583 records and LINQ version of it is returning all of the 30613 records

Comment: It's great that you show your own efforts, but could you also tell why it apparently doesn't do what you try to achieve? Also, usually joins can be solved by using navigation properties, rather than LINQ joins.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks !!, Sorry I missed that one actually when I ran the sql query it returns 30583 records but running same thing in LINQ returns all of the 30613 records. Also, I can use Navigational properties because that will eventually loads a million of records into memeory

Comment: Your SQL and your LINQ statements don't do the same thing.  That probably explains the difference in returned rows.  What is your _actual_ SQL?

Comment: Can you please provide some sql code, which will create tables and also will allow to insert some initial values into tables in order to understand what your code does?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy I cant give the actual tables but, assume that both tables contains UVID and DocID and Table UserViewHeader contains on more field IsLock. Now, what i want is all the records from UserViewDoc except for those records for which IsLock is true from particular UVID

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the query to be exactly like the sql query, i believe that this is the way:

```
var firstQuery = (from u in this.ViewSelectorControl.LDReviewContext.GetTable<UserViewDoc>()
                  where IDs.Contains(u.UVID)
                  select u.DocID).Distinct();

var innerQuery = (from u in this.ViewSelectorControl.LDReviewContext.GetTable<UserViewDoc>()
                      join uvh in this.ViewSelectorControl.LDReviewContext.GetTable<UserViewHeader>() on uvh.UVID equals u.UVID
                      where IDs.Contains(u.UIVD) == false
                      && uvh.IsLock
                      select u.DocID).Distinct();

var resultQuery = from f in firstQuery
                  join i in innerQuery on i equals f into lout
                  from i in lout.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where i == null
                  select f;
```